# Xamarin android Worker

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have old xamarin android jobintentservice I'm replacing to support android 12.0.

I now inherit Worker instead of JobIntentService, and use WorkManager to enqueue its job.

Couple of questions:

1. Is there a way use await inside DoWork override method?
2. Is it better to inherit ListenableWorker instead in order to use await? Do I lose
   anything if I switch to it?
3. If I Task.Factory.StartNew(LongRunning) from Worker's DoWork, and immediately that follow with return success result, will my long running task run to completion, or all work associated will be terminated?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can know more about `WorkManager` first.

From document [Schedule tasks with WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) we know that:

WorkManager is the recommended solution for persistent work. Work is persistent when it remains scheduled through app restarts and system reboots. Because most background processing is best accomplished through persistent work, WorkManager is the primary recommended API for background processing.

**WorkManager handles three types of persistent work:**

- Immediate: Tasks that must begin immediately and complete soon. May
  be expedited.
- Long Running: Tasks which might run for longer, potentially longer
  than 10 minutes.
- Deferrable: Scheduled tasks that start at a later time and can run
  periodically.

And from the [Work chaining](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager#work) of Features,we know

For complex related work, [chain individual work tasks together](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/chain-work) using an intuitive interface that allows you to control which pieces run sequentially and which run in parallel.

```
WorkManager.getInstance(...)
.beginWith(Arrays.asList(workA, workB))
.then(workC)
.enqueue();
```

For each work task, you can define input and output data for that work. When chaining work together, WorkManager automatically passes output data from one work task to the next.

**Note:**

If you still have any problem, get back to me.

Comment: Ok, so as I understand it, chaining work requests allows me to 'await' their completion. But then I have to support each work request cancelling/error and how to handle them. It's a lot work instead of a couple of real awaits. Regarding my original questions....?

Comment: Each work is independent, is there no relationship?

Comment: Because there is a relation, I do not wish to make it separate work requests

Comment: Then you can try to use [Work chaining](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager#work)  to achieve your function.

Comment: Again, this will require several separate Worker classes, with each one doing part of the job. Then, I'll need to handle each worker error/cancellations separately. I feel his makes it much more complicated...

Comment: Then you can try to use `await - async ` to achieve this.